# WP migration - permalinks not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I migrated my wp site by saving the home directory and db and uploading them to the new site. 
Permalinks are set to /%postname%/

**The problem is links for pages like https://example.com/page show blank**, not even 404; they work only with "**/**" in the end. Also, some links in the wp-admin (e.g to delete something) work, but show blank and do not return to the previous page/screen. Saving new permalink settings in Wp admin shows a blank screen.

I would like to make links work both with "/" and without in the end.
I tried many things for the htaccess, didn't work.

This is my htaccess file from before migration:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
```

I don't know why all is messed up now.

Comment: 1st check network console what is your page status in network 200 or 500? then Comment out the HTTPS and reset permalinks to simple page ID settings.

Comment: Did this. Now what? If I delete a user (and confirm) I get a blank page and so on..

Comment: have you check error logs? and i think your SSL configuration is not properly set on hosting or domain.